# How do I add just the transitive dependencies of one Gradle configuration to another?

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj

I am attempting to write a Gradle plugin that modifies the JARs of dependencies (by weaving with AspectJ during build). However, due to how I'm modifying them, I need to use the unmodified versions at compile time and replace those with the modified versions at run time. So, in my plugin, I created a configuration for the user to add the dependencies that need to be modified. I would like to make it so that the plugin adds those immediate dependencies to the compile-only classpath, adds the modified versions of those immediate dependencies as runtime-only classpath, and adds the unmodified transitive dependencies to both the compile and runtime classpath.

My issue is how can I add just the transitive dependencies of that configuration to the runtime classpath without adding the direct dependencies?

It seems impossible, because, to get the transitive dependencies, I need to resolve my configuration before the runtime configuration, so I can add some of the resolved dependencies of my configuration that to the runtime configuration before the runtime configuration is resolved.

As a side note, I've been relying on the ordering of the classpath so that I can include both the modified and unmodified versions at runtime and it uses the modified version. However, I think that might not be working for dynamically resolved classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for my [monkey patch plugin](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-monkey-patch/blob/master/java-monkey-patch/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/JavaMonkeyPatchPlugin.groovy) where I get the transitive dependencies of a "target" dependency without the "target" itself

Interesting snippets

```
            configurations {
                monkeyPatchNonTransitive { transitive = false }
                monkeyPatchTransitive
            }
```

And

```
                dependencies {
                    monkeyPatchTransitive target
                    monkeyPatchNonTransitive target
                    compileOnly(target) {
                        transitive = false
                    }
                }

                Set<Map>  depSet = [] as Set
                ResolvedDependency topDependency = configurations.monkeyPatchTransitive.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.iterator().next()
                topDependency.children.each { ResolvedDependency child ->
                    child.allModuleArtifacts.each { ResolvedArtifact artifact ->
                        ModuleVersionIdentifier mvi = artifact.moduleVersion.id
                        def dependency = [
                                group  : mvi.group,
                                name   : mvi.name,
                                version: mvi.version,
                                ext    : artifact.extension
                        ]
                        if (artifact.classifier) {
                            dependency['classifier'] = artifact.classifier
                        }
                        depSet << dependency
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I have a multi-project setup and one of the projects has a lot of common code that I don't want duplicated in the others. I also am unable to publish the common project on its own so it was really looking like a dead-end until I saw this answer.

THANK YOU!